# python django race condition with celery

Tags: python, mysql, django, celery, django-celery

Working on a python django project, here is what I want:

1. User access `Page1` with object argument, function `longFunction()` of the object is triggered and passed to celery so the page can be returned immediately
2. If user tries to access `Page2` with same object argument, I want the page to hang until  object function `longFunction()` triggered by `Page1` is terminated.

So I tried by locking mysql db row with objects.select_for_update() but it doesn't work.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
def Page1(request, arg_id):
    obj = Vm.objects.select_for_update().get(id=arg_id)
    obj.longFunction.delay()
    return render_to_response(...)

def Page2(request, arg_id):
    vm = Vm.objects.select_for_update().get(id=arg_id)
    return render_to_response(...)
```

I want that `Page2` hangs at the line `vm = Vm.objects.select_for_update().get(id=arg_id)` until `longFunction()` is completed. I'm new to celery and it looks like the mysql connection initiated on Page1 is lost when the Page1 returns, even if `longFunction()` is not finished.

Is there another way I can achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be helpul for you:

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from yourapp.celery import app

def Page1(request, arg_id):
    obj = Vm.objects.select_for_update().get(id=arg_id)
    celery_task_id = obj.longFunction.delay()
    return render_to_response(...)

def Page2(request, arg_id, celery_task_id):
    task = AsyncResult(app=app, id=celery_task_id)
    state = task.state
    while state != "SUCCESFUL":
        # wait or do whatever you want
    vm = Vm.objects.select_for_update().get(id=arg_id)
    return render_to_response(...)
```

More info at http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.states.html

Comment: Note that it's better to wait in the frontend, you can take a look at jobtastic for example: http://policystat.github.io/jobtastic/ which makes this simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The database lock from `select_for_update` is released when the transaction closes (in page 1). This lock doesn't get carried to the celery task. You can lock in the celery task but that won't solve your problem because page 2 might get loaded before the celery task obtains the lock.

Mikel's answer will work. You could also put a lock in the cache as described in [the celery cookbook](http://ask.github.io/celery/cookbook/tasks.html).